# Does ECC RAM help in a home-use NAS?

Tags: memory, network-attached-storage, ecc

Do i need to use ECC RAM if i'm only going to use a 100TB Server for video file storing, organizing and copying files on and off of it ? 
The build will be Asrock X370 Taichi + Ryzen 3 + Windows 10 Storage Spaces

Comment: Enable hash summing inside your file system (ReFS) or FS + logical volume manager (ZFS) and you'll be good.

Comment: Home use  not topical on SF.

Comment: There is no ZFS cause i'm not using freeNAS but Storage Spaces

Answer (score 4):

There is a possibility that data is corrupted while sitting in memory. If this happens to a read buffer it's bad. If it happens to write buffer it's worse - it'll get written to disk and stay there, corrupted.

However, the probability is usually very low. It depends on the exact type and quality of memory you're using, the amount of background radiation, a few other factors - and how long the data actually sits in memory before being (re)used or written out. This tends to be much longer on servers than on clients which in turn leads to frequent use of ECC memory in server systems.

Whether you 'need' ECC RAM or not depends on how valuable your data is and what the ECC option costs.

Comment: The data will sit in memory for years to come, 10-20+ years, who knows, it's my personal video collection. So then ECC RAM would help right ? The price difference is ~50$ between 8gb of ECC vs non- ECC RAM. The other components support ECC (Asrock and Ryzen)

Comment: "sit in memory" as "sit in RAM" - the data mainly sits on the disks and is only loaded when requested (more or less). The exact time spent depends on the workload which I'd guess will be pretty low. So no, you won't need ECC but it won't hurt either.

Comment: Thanks Zac, if it wont hurt then i guess it's worth the extra 60$

Answer (score 1):

No.

Why? If you want a business class gear then buy one with support please. As do you have a UPS, a battery pack on that controller, do you use the onboard raid controller? Its non professional from the start. (and not counting the windows 10 used as a server)

Save those bucks

Comment: Care to elaborate on why that is? It sounds like a strange claim that potential corruption from RAM isn't important, would help if you clarified the reasoning.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist the context is for home usage, all home product for nas, dlink, etc.. all don't use ecc ram.

Comment: That argument pretty much leads to "only price is important", though? Not "disk controllers and network cards are important".

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist No, this argument is if he want a business class gear then he buy one with support. The op will prebuild something with a windows 10 to host his storage, is it professional? Does he have a UPS, a battery pack on that controller? Its non professional from the start.

Comment: Imo, that last comment would make for a much better answer to the question.

Comment: What does a UPS have to do with ECC RAM ? Completely off topic. You clearly have no idea what you're talking about. What RAID controler ? I specifically said i'm using Storage Spaces (software RAID) not hardware RAID. (for many reasons)